# Accessing NSStrings from other classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

i hope you can help me solving my actual problem:

I´ve set up a new project with a navigation controller. For the table view of the project I´ve added a new class for it, called "TableViewController.h" and "TableViewController.m".

In this class I´ve declared in .h a property for a NSString to access it from other classes, like this:

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *testString;
```

In .m I´ve synthesized it as followed:

```
    @synthesize testString;
```

Now I set in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath-Method of the table view controller the following:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     testString = @"Hello, World!";
    }
```

Now created a new UIViewController class for the next view which should appear when I´m tapping on a cell (all that works so far). In this UIViewController, called "SecondView" I imported the .h-File of TableViewController.
Further I have this code in SecondView.m:

```
    -(void) viewDidLoad
    {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     TableViewController *demoObject = [TableViewController alloc] init]
     NSLog (@"Teststring is: %@" [demoObject.testString]);
    }
```

Now when I start the Simulator I get this Output:
Teststring is: (null)

When I NSLog the testString in TableViewController I get "Hello, World", but why isn´t it "transferred" to the SecondView class and generates the needed output?

Comment: Please try to understand object-oriented programming.  Doing `[[TableViewController alloc] init]` creates a new instance of that class which is totally separate from any other instance of the class you may have previously created.  As a result, any values set in previously-created instances will not be accessible from the new instance.

Comment: Oh dear, you´re so right! That was a push into the right direction, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are logging the string in `viewDidLoad`, which gets called long before it is set in the table views's `didSelectRow` method. You should also use `self.testString = ...`

Comment: +1. This. You create the table then immediately log the string. How could the user select a cell and set the string to something before the view has been loaded? xD

Comment: ...I think the problem was the confusing way he wrote it. :p

Comment: @Metabble: The way he wrote it reflected his own confusion. (This is very common and looking for it is a good way to see through to the real problem.)

Comment: @Peter Hosey It may be very common, but I found this particular post hard to follow. Probably because I'm tired.

Answer (score 0):

how do you expect the data to 'transfer'? you have to **pass** it .. in tableView:didSelectCellAt:row (where you push the 2nd view) you have to say:

```
2ndView.testString = self.testString;
```